# Adding Ghost blog to a React App Route instead of subdomain

Tags: heroku, seo, cname, firebase-hosting, ghost

I have been told to add a blog to a route for SEO purposes instead of subdomain. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this for a React app hosted on Firebase. Currently my Ghost bLog is hosted through heroku on my apps subdomain, I want to move it to an route. i.e instead of blog.myapp.com I want myapp.com/blog. How exactly can I achieve this, Using CNAME for the route(is that possible)?

Comment: If I understand properly the intent, I think you would need Firebase to reverse proxy requests for your /blog route to the actual location, such as with nginx or apache's mod_proxy. Looks like Firebase supports rewrites (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites) but not sure about reverse proxy.

Comment: You can't use a CNAME to tell myapp.com/blog to go somewhere. Nothing can be defined after the root domain. You *could* use a CNAME to route requests to blog.myapp.com to myapp.com/blog, but I don't think that will help you as the SEO would still be an issue. Agree with Kevin above, a reverse proxy is the best solution.